# Flutter Firestore - how to get the current month's data only?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

everyone. In the query below how can I get only the data for the current month?

my firestore DB:

[image]

my code:

```
@override
Stream<List<TodoModel>> getTodos() {
 return firestore.collection('todo')
  .orderBy('myDate', descending: true)
  .snapshots()
  .map((query) {
   return query.documents.map((doc) {
    return TodoModel.fromDocument(doc);
  }).toList();
 });
}
```

Any idea how I can do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this

```dart
 Stream<List<TodoModel>> getTodos() {
    var date =  DateTime.now();
    return Firestore.instance.collection('todo')
        .where('myDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: new DateTime(date.year, date.month, 1))
        .orderBy('myDate', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) {
      return query.documents.map((doc) {
        return TodoModel.fromDocument(doc);
      }).toList();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's a shame we can't avoid the next month.

Comment: You can do that too. You can add another where condition to do that

Comment: Yes, I think I can handle it that way: `.where('myDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: new DateTime(now.year, now.month + 1, 0))`

Comment: use 1 instead of 0 it will reduce one month and change the date to last day of the month

Comment: Thanks, for me 0(zero) is perfect.